# pass useState from child to parent using functional components with typescript and react native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, state, use-state

I have a table in my Header component configured like this :

```
const Header = ({ setHome }) => {
  const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newTabIndex: number) => {
    setTabIndex(newTabIndex);
  };

  const setHomeChange = () => {
    setHome((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      showCropManagement: !prevState.showCropManagement,
      showDashboard: !prevState.showDashboard,
    }));
  };

  const tabProps = (index: number) => {
    return {
      id: `tab-${index}`,
      "aria-controls": `tab-${index}`,
    };
  }

  return (
    <View style={rootStylesheet.container}>
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%", height: "10%" }}>
        <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
          <Tabs value={tabIndex} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="tabs">
            <Tab
              label="Dashboard"
              onClick={tabIndex === 1 ? setHomeChange : undefined}
              {...tabProps(0)}
            />
            <Tab
              label="Crop Management"
              onClick={tabIndex === 0 ? setHomeChange : undefined}
              {...tabProps(1)}
            />
          </Tabs>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </View>
  );
```

and my Home Component like this :

```
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [home, setHome] = React.useState({
    showCropManagement: false,
    showDashboard: true,
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={rootMUITheme}>
      <Header setHome={setHome} />

      <View>
        {home.showCropManagement && <CropManagement navigation={navigation} />}
        {home.showDashboard && <Dashboard navigation={navigation} />}
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>Footer</Text>
      </View>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

In Home I have 2 Tabs Dashboard and Crop Management. When I click to go to Crop Management Tab. the state changes correctly and the crop management component is loaded but the Tab is not set as Active as you can see in this picture :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hegue.png

The active Tab is blocked in the first Tab

Thank you

Comment: Hi, you have to explain what the issue is exactly, or at least provide a reproduceable issue on snack expo.

Comment: @BARNOWL i edited the question i hope it's more clear

Comment: Its still not clear, when making questions make it concise, and straight to the point of what your issue is, what is the actual result vs the expected result. Format it in a way that its easy to understand.

Comment: please check again and sorry for bothering i added a picture

Comment: Did you come to a resolution ? I would suggest reproducing this on stackblitz, or snack expo.